# How to W3C validate php image resize script

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I use a php image resize script which is invoked using:

```
<img src="/images/image.php?img=test.png&maxw=100&maxh=100" alt="This is a test image" />
```

but this does not W3C validate. Are there anyways to get this to validate?

Comment: What's the error in W3C validator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you havn't given an exact eror-message, i have to assume the validation fails because of the ampersands. just take a look at [the error description](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp) (wich also should be directly linked to from the validation-report, so you could have easily found this on your own) to see how to solve this.

> To avoid problems with both validators and browsers, always use **&amp;**
>   in place of **&** when writing URLs in HTML.

that said, just change your code to:

```
... src="/images/image.php?img=test.png&amp;maxw=100&amp;maxh=100" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with PHP. All you need to do is turn those `&` characters into entities:

```
<img src="/images/image.php?img=test.png&amp;maxw=100&amp;maxh=100" alt="This is a test image" />
```

Really though, it's not that big of a deal. No browser (that I'm aware of) will misinterpret this, but if you want perfect validation then that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you output such URLs from PHP you can use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to automatically convert e.g. `&` to `&amp;`

> htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

**Example:**

```
$path = "/images/image.php?img=test.png&maxw=100&maxh=100";
$path = htmlentities($path);
echo $path;
```

This would output this in your html:

```
/images/image.php?img=test.png&amp;maxw=100&amp;maxh=100
```